# strings and keyboard inputs in java

Tags: java, string, keyboard, case, switch-statement

I need to write a Java program which reads in a string from the keyboard and then reports how many times each letter of the alphabet occurs within that string (ignoring case). It should also report how many non-letters are included in the string.

but I don't even know where to begin

if someone is willing to write this program for me and/or take me through it step by step I would be very grateful. Heck if someone just wrote the program for be I would be willing to pay (and I can- email me for details)

Comment: Go see RentACoder - StackOverflow was never meant to be a homework service.

Answer (score 2):

Stack overflow is not a place where you should ask people to do your homework for you, there are other websites for that.

I could answer your question, as many other people here could, but if you're ever going to learn how to program you'd better do your homework yourself.

If you can't figure out where to begin, check out these websites:

lower casing:
download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)

going over characters:
download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/text/StringCharacterIterator.html

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/StrIter.html

Answer (score 1):

- Read input from System.in
- Loop on each character of the input string
- Put character count in a Map
- Print report

There you go.